# Calculating variance accurately in Python

Tags: python, list, statistics

I am calculating variance of list `A` which contains many sublists. However, the output is different from a mathematical calculation. Why is that? I present the current and expected output.

```
import statistics

A = [[2], [7], [3], [12], [9]]

# Flatten the sublists to get a single list of values
flattened_values = [value for sublist in A for value in sublist]

# Calculate the variance using the statistics module
variance_value = statistics.variance(flattened_values)

print("Variance:", variance_value)
```

The current output is

```
Variance: 17.3
```

The expected output is

```
13.84
```

Comment: There are different definitions of sigma^2 depending on whether you use n or (n-1) degrees of freedom. If you multiply the current output 17.3 by (n-1)/n, which means 4/5 in your case, you will get the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `statistics.variance()` method calculates the variance from a sample of data (from a population)
To calculate the variance of an entire population, look at the `statistics.pvariance()` method

```
import statistics

A = [[2], [7], [3], [12], [9]]

# Flatten the sublists to get a single list of values
flattened_values = [value for sublist in A for value in sublist]

# Calculate the variance using the statistics module
variance_value = statistics.pvariance(flattened_values)

print("Variance:", variance_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use numpy.

```py
import numpy as np

A = [[2], [7], [3], [12], [9]]

A = [value for sublist in A for value in sublist]
# can also do A = np.array(A).flatten()
print("Variance:", np.var(A))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation to get your expected result, you must use **pvariance** method not **variance**